# Software architecture map to aid cross team communication?

Tags: organization

I work in a company where multiple teams each work on different parts of a software product in a vaguely agile/scrum manner. Mostly the organisation works well but there have been instances where a team may make a change without realising its impact on other teams.

Where dependence is known communication has been good, and where dependence is suspected then 'broadcast' emails and informal conversations have also worked well. But there exists a sub-set of tasks that fall between the cracks. Broadcast emails are likely not the solution as they would become too numerous such that the email signal/noise ratio would fall.

I'm contemplating a solution that involves a sort of map of the software, which details all of the various parts of the system and loosely tries to place interacting and dependent parts near to each other. Each developer then updates their position on the map (today I'm working on X and Y), and therefore if two or more developers happen to be co-located (or proximate) on the map then we can see this each day and this could form the trigger for further discussion on possible overlap and conflict.

Is such a method out there and in use? If so what is it and does it work? Otherwise, do you think such a scheme has merit?

Comment: Are you practicing TDD, or at least have all of the code adequately covered by unit tests?

Comment: What is your repository and deployment scenario? Do all teams work on a shared repository that has one build and deployment? Can you split it into multiple repositories each dealing with different features or components that are loosely coupled and just deployed to the same server? I know you're looking for a process solution here, but most teams solve it with architecture (e.g. SOA).

Comment: We do have localised unit tests, at a larger scale the system is fairly brittle to changes such that 'user journey' scripts tend to get broken very quickly by new work. I would also add that using tests to detect overlap requires work to be performed and checked-in to source control, hence effort has been exerted on development prior to the conflict being detected.

Comment: @Aaronaught We do have a lot of separation at the technology level, i.e. layers of functionality. But at the highest levels we have a sort of process flow that directs navigation around a web site and what data goes in and out of each step in the process. It's this high level where most of the issue is. There is also a database which tends to have tables that are common use but which may get extended to drive specific functionality. (it's complicated!)

Comment: This is definitely a solution that could use solving, but imposing more process on developers is going to get lots of pushback.  Perhaps inferring position on the map as a function of files touched/checked out in their local working set.

Comment: @SteveEvers Nice idea. I suspect most of the map could be generated automatically also, using some bespoke code to identify the dependencies. That code would likely require updating from time to time, but there would be an incentive to do that if it was seen to be working well.

Comment: How are tasks tracked and assigned? How many teams do you have?

Comment: The # of teams changes but about 6 on average. Each team works on one area of the system, and the tasks within each team are ordered logically and team members decide amongst themselves which task to do next (based on skill set, priorities, etc.). Tracking is with little cards on whiteboards and a daily 15 min stand-up meeting/discussion.